# Infinite slick slider not sliding left

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

I have a slick slider with a few images in it but scrolling left doesn't seem to work.

here is my slick slider code:

```
$('.items_functions').slick({
  infinite: true,
  centerMode: true,
  slidesToShow: 3,
  swipeToSlide: true,
  variableWidth: true,
});
```

I have infinite scrolling on though when i scroll to the left,
I can only scroll 4 images

Comment: make sure you have enough elements

Comment: Could you put it to codesandbox (or something similar) where it can be reproduced?

Comment: Where is your html ??